# Android Calendarview set focused date ( Previous and Next month)

Tags: android, date, calendarview

I'm using calendarview library and I have a "Previous" and "Next" buttons.
Can you please help me move the focus to the "Previous" month and "Next" month?

the codes below does not work for me..

```
 // format date and display on screen
        final Calendar dat = Calendar.getInstance();
        dat.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        dat.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        dat.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
```

I appreciate the help.

Comment: what you want to focus? the date of the next month?!

Comment: yes and the previous month as well. :)

Comment: why don't you use `setselection()` method and pass `i` as the integer variable which will calculate the day of the particular month

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are setting the new date in the `CalendarView`.

The code that you want would look something like this (for getting the previous month)

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // Get today
cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1); // get previous month by substracting one to the current one
long previousMonth = cal.getTimeInMillis(); // get the milliseconds of previous month
calendarView.setDate(previousMonth); // set in the CalendarView that you want to see the previous month
```

The code for moving forward is just a matter of changing the line

```
 cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1); // get previous month
```

to

```
 cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1); // get following month
```